# Why shell_exec return null

Tags: php, symfony, yii2

I have a shell command which runs fine in cmd,
but when I want to run this command in php using shell_exec() function it returns null to me, and I tried with exec() function, same thing.

I read an article saying that shell_exec returns NULL if an error occurred.

This is what I did in my  yii2 code:

```
$strPath = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyApp";
chdir ($strPath);
return $output = shell_exec ('php app/console command ........');
```

This command its symfony command.
Knowing that the project is in windows server.

How can we solve this problem?
It is true that there is a problem

please help me

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the Symfony framework or just components? Where do you call `shell_exec()` from, a Symfony Controller, or where?

Comment: "On Windows, the underlying pipe is opened in text mode which can cause the function to fail for binary output. Consider to use popen() instead for such cases."

Comment: @Arleigh Hix I call sell_exec() from yii2 Controller, and command it's symfony command

Comment: why not using `exec`?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

`Note: This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.`